C# ApiController : multiple authentication methods
We have an ASP.NET Core 7 Web API controller and we use Azure AD B2C as the main authentication which works fine. We need a single end point to be basic auth. I've tried creating a custom authorization handler which does this and that works fine. I can see it working through and doing context.Succeed but I still get a 401 response from my call. It's as if it's then doing the Azure AD B2C check which fails.
I've tried putting [AllowAnonymous] attribute on the endpoint as well as [Authorize(Policy = "BasicAuth")] but then no auth is applied.
public class BasicAuthHandler : AuthorizationHandler<BasicAuthRequirement>
{
     private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
     private readonly AppSettings _settings;

     public BasicAuthHandler(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor, IOptions<AppSettings> settings)
     {
         _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
         _settings = settings.Value;
     }

     protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, BasicAuthRequirement requirement)
     {
         if (ValidateBasicAuth(_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext))
         {
             context.Succeed(requirement);
         }
         else
         {
             var response = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Response;
             response.Clear();
             response.StatusCode = 401;
             context.Fail();
         }

         return Task.CompletedTask;
     }

     private bool ValidateBasicAuth(HttpContext context)
     {
         string authHeader = context.Request.Headers["Authorization"];

         if (authHeader != null && authHeader.StartsWith("Basic"))
         {
             string encodedUsernamePassword = authHeader.Substring("Basic ".Length).Trim();
             Encoding encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1");
             string usernamePassword = encoding.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(encodedUsernamePassword));

             int seperatorIndex = usernamePassword.IndexOf(':');

             var username = usernamePassword.Substring(0, seperatorIndex);
             var password = usernamePassword.Substring(seperatorIndex + 1);
             if (username.Equals(_settings.BasicAuth.Username, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && password.Equals(_settings.BasicAuth.Password))
                 return true;
         }

         return false;
     }
}

How do I setup two different authentication methods for separate endpoints?

Authentication methods are configured at program startup and used by the authentication middleware, not the Authorize attribute that simply says a specific controller or action requires authentication before it's even called. Why do you want basic authentication in the first place? It's so insecure (and costly) the .NET team explicitly removed it (Barry Dorans is an MS security guy). Using a better authentication method is actually easier than implementing basic authentication

It's for claim enrichment from azure AD B2C so has to be Basic auth.

Authorization and Authentication are two distinct terms, that mean different things.
In short words Authentication consists of Identification (finding out who the caller is) and verification whether they are who they say they are. For example in Basic auth example UserName tells you who the caller is and PassWord allows you to verify whether they truly are that Identity.
Authorization on the other hand is checking whether caller's Identity has access to certain resources or operations in your application.
The atrributes you mentioned [AllowAnonymous] and [Authorize] apply to authorization part.
BTW, if you want to use named authorization policies you have to first define them in your application startup, for example:
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    var policy1 = new YourAuthorizationPolicy1();
    var policy2 = new YourAuthorizationPolicy2();

    options.AddPolicy("PolicyName1", policy1);
    options.AddPolicy("PolicyName2", policy2);
    options.DefaultPolicy = policy1;
});

Similarly you can define multiple Authentication schemes in your application startup, which I believe answers your question.
In example below the app would accept Basic auth and Bearer auth.
services.AddAuthentication().AddScheme<BasicAuthOptions, BasicAuthHandler>("Basic", options =>
{
})
.AddBearerToken("Bearer", options =>
{
});

Please note, that your BasicAuthHandler has to inherit AuthenticationHandler, instead of AuthorizationHandler
Note that the ASP.Net inf code will enumerate all registered authentication handlers and for each try to get caller's Identity
Authorization happens lot later int he pipeline then Authentication, so I suggest if you want to have custom Authorization policies allowing only callers authenticating in certain way, your Authentication handlers can add specific claim to the created Identity, that you could use for Authorization.
Hope this helps.

This sounds like what I need but I don't want other end points to allow Basic Auth. Does this allow for that?

Adding [BasicAuthentication] attribute to the controller end points seems to do the trick!

yes, the code snippets I provided control would authentication schemens for all controllers, hence the note of additional filtering on authorization level if needed.
I'm glad you found your solution, could you please mark the response as accepted?
